# Use AnySequence and anyGenerator in combination

Tags: swift, generics

Another question asked, essentially, how to implement a `take` function which would return the first n elements of a sequence.  My answer was:

```
struct TakeFromSequenceSequence<S:SequenceType> : SequenceType {
    var limit : Int
    var sequence : S

    func generate() -> AnyGenerator<S.Generator.Element> {
        var generator = sequence.generate()
        var limit = self.limit

        return anyGenerator {
            guard limit > 0 else {
                return nil
            }

            limit = limit - 1

            return generator.next()
        }
    }
}

extension SequenceType {
    func take(count:Int) -> TakeFromSequenceSequence<Self> {
        return TakeFromSequenceSequence(limit: count, sequence: self)
    }
}
```

but it seems like I ought to be able to use `AnySequence` and `anyGenerator` to do it all inline in my take function:

```
extension SequenceType {
    func take(count:Int) -> AnySequence<Self.Generator.Element> {
        // cannot invoke initializer for type 'AnySequence<_>' with an argument list of type '(() -> _)'
        return AnySequence({
            var generator = self.generate()
            var limit = count

            // cannot invoke 'anyGenerator' with an argument list of type '(() -> _)'
            return anyGenerator({
                guard limit > 0 else {
                    return nil
                }

                limit = limit - 1

                return generator.next()
            })
        })
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, this yields multiple typing errors, mostly (I think) because type inference is failing.

Anybody have any suggestions on how to get this (using `AnySequence` and `anyGenerator` inline) to work?

Comment: I notice that it does compile if you specify the element type up front, e.g. `extension SequenceType where Self.Generator.Element == Int` and then you can say `<Int>` in all the right places. I bet that fact is a clue...

Comment: Yeah, it really seems to be a case of the type inference not being able to figure it out, just hoping there's something (obvious?) that I'm missing.

Comment: And you can't make the type explicit (`AnySequence<Self.Generator.Element>(...)`) because the syntax doesn't seem to allow it, it complains about the < being an illegal operator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*(The answer is now based on Swift 2.2/Xcode 7.3. A solution for Swift 2.1 can be found in the edit history.)*

The type of the closure passed to the `AnySequence` init method 
must be specified explicitly:

```
extension SequenceType {
    func take(count:Int) -> AnySequence<Generator.Element> {

        return AnySequence { () -> AnyGenerator<Generator.Element> in
            var generator = self.generate()
            var limit = count
            return AnyGenerator {  
                guard limit > 0 else {
                    return nil
                }
                limit = limit - 1
                return generator.next()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note that the (redundant) `Self.` in `Self.Generator.Element` is omitted, otherwise it does not compile.

Example:

```
let sequence = [1,2,3,4,5].take(2)
print(Array(sequence)) // [1, 2]
print(Array(sequence)) // [1, 2]
```

Alternatively, the method can be defined as

```
extension SequenceType {
    func take(count:Int) -> AnySequence<Generator.Element> {

        var generator = self.generate()
        var limit = count

        return AnySequence {
            return AnyGenerator {  
                guard limit > 0 else {
                    return nil
                }
                limit = limit - 1
                return generator.next()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now the closure passed to the `AnySequence` init method is a "single-expression closure" and the type is inferred by the compiler.

But – as David Berry noted – the created sequence then behaves differently, the `generate()` method cannot be called repeatedly
with identical results:

```
let sequenceX = [1,2,3,4,5].take(2)
print(Array(sequenceX)) // [1, 2]
print(Array(sequenceX)) // []
```

This *is permitted behavior*, as stated in the [`SequenceType` protocol reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios//documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_SequenceType_Protocol/index.html):

> ... It is not correct to assume that a sequence will either be
>   "consumable" and will resume iteration, or that a sequence is a
>   collection and will restart iteration from the first element. A
>   conforming sequence that is not a collection is allowed to produce an
>   arbitrary sequence of elements from the second generator.

So one can choose among these implementations, dependent on the desired behavior.

Comment: I don't think the second option does the same thing (generate can't be called repeatedly because generator and limit are captured outside the block)

Comment: `() -> AnyGenerator<Self.Generator.Element> in` is exactly where I got stuck. :)

Comment: There we go, it was using the typealias line to fix `() -> Self.Generator.Element` that I was missing in my attempts.

Comment: Both versions worked in a simple test. I *assume* that the `var`s are captured by reference.

Comment: The point of SequenceType is to allow `generate` to be invoked multiple times, each time restarting the iteration.  A simple for loop won't test that (not really sure what a simple way would be).  Your second example would fail that as the second iteration would yield `[]`

Comment: The code `var sequence = [1,2,3,4,5].take2(2);print(Array(sequence));
print(Array(sequence))` should yield the same result for both prints, but the second attempt won't, the first will.

Comment: @DavidBerry: You are right. I have removed the second part. (I *thought* that I had seen that pattern before, but I am not sure anymore.)

Comment: No worries, you gave me the real solution, which may help for some other attempts I'm making.